# Parameterized JUnit Test

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, junit, parameterized

**QUESTION:**
After putting my `initialization` into the actual `@Parameters` I no longer have a NullPointerException, is it possiuble that @Before isn't actually invoked before?!
Is there a solution so I don't have to put it into my Paramters?

**Solution:**

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class XQTest4Test {
    static XQueryTestHelper buildTest;
    static HeaderBodyPayloadTestcase[] arrayHdrInbPayTestcases;


    @Before
    public void initialize() throws Exception {
        buildTest = new XQueryTestHelper();
        buildTest.initialization();

        arrayHdrInbPayTestcases = buildTest.getHdrInbPayTestcases();
        System.out.println(arrayHdrInbPayTestcases[0].a);
    }

        @Parameter
        public HeaderBodyPayloadTestcase testcase;

        @Parameters(name = "{index}: pew")
        public static Iterable<? extends HeaderBodyPayloadTestcase> data() throws Exception {
            buildTest = new XQueryTestHelper();
            buildTest.initialization();

            arrayHdrInbPayTestcases = buildTest.getHdrInbPayTestcases();
            return Arrays.asList(arrayHdrInbPayTestcases);
        }




    @Test
    public void someTest() throws Exception{
    //  System.out.println(xq.toString());
        System.out.println(testcase.a);
        if(testcase.c.contains("HDR")){
            assertTrue(new XQueryTester(testcase.a,testcase.b).testHeader(testcase.c,testcase.d));
        }
        else if (testcase.c.contains("PAY")){
            assertTrue(new XQueryTester(testcase.a,testcase.b).testBody(testcase.c,testcase.d));

        }
        else {
            assertTrue(new XQueryTester(testcase.a,testcase.b).testInbound(testcase.c,testcase.d));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please post the **complete** error message

Comment: @TimothyTruckle done

Answer (score 0):

I think `@Parameter` annotation should help you. In this way you do not need a constructor with parameters.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class XQTest4Test {
    static XQueryTestHelper buildTest;
    static HeaderBodyPayloadTestcase[] arrayHdrInbPayTestcases;

    @Parameter
    public HeaderBodyPayloadTestcase testcase;

    @Parameters(name = "{index}: pew")
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new HeaderBodyPayloadTestcase[][]{arrayHdrInbPayTestcases});
    }

    // ...

}
```

And ensure that access modifier of field marked as `@Parameter` is `public`.

I would recommend you to do all the initialization in `@Before` or `@BeforeClass` methods. Depends on you logic.

This feature is well-documented on [*JUnit4 wiki*](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests)

Comment: I did that?

`@Parameterized.Parameter(0)
    public HeaderAndBodyTestcase xq;`

Changed to your suggestion, still same error.

Comment: @Hendrik have you removed the constructor?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at XQTest4Test.someTest(XQTest4Test.java:68)` 
 public HeaderAndBodyTestcase xq;
Line 68:   `if(xq.c.contains("HDR")){`